# Locking GPU frequency on a rooted Samsung Galaxy S10 with Mali-G76 for Flutter app performance testing

Tags: android, flutter, gpu, adb, performance-testing

I'm currently working on performance testing for my Flutter app on Android, following Filip Hracek's guide: [Performance testing of Flutter apps](https://medium.com/flutter/performance-testing-of-flutter-apps-df7669bb7df7).

My test device is a rooted Samsung Galaxy S10 (SM-G973F), where CPU throttling works as expected. However, I'm facing issues when trying to lock the GPU frequency. The guide uses a Nexus 5 with Qualcomm GPU, but the S10 uses an ARM Mali-G76, and the script provided in the guide does not apply. Here's the problematic section of the script: [GPU locking code](https://github.com/2d-inc/developer_quest/blob/master/tool/lock_android_scaling.sh#L107).

I found potential GPU settings in the device, such as:

```bash
adb shell "cat /sys/kernel/gpu/gpu_freq_table"
# 156000 200000 260000 325000 377000 433000 572000 650000 702000
```

Attempting to lock the GPU frequency with the following commands only temporarily changes the values. The selected governor remains, but the frequency values revert after a few seconds:

```bash
GPU_FREQ="325000"
GPU_GOV="Default"
adb shell "echo ${GPU_GOV} > /sys/kernel/gpu/gpu_governor"
adb shell "echo ${GPU_FREQ} > /sys/kernel/gpu/gpu_min_clock"
adb shell "echo ${GPU_FREQ} > /sys/kernel/gpu/gpu_max_clock"
adb shell "echo ${GPU_FREQ} > /sys/kernel/gpu/gpu_mm_min_clock"
```

I've tried all available GPU governors (**Default, Interactive, Joint, Static, Booster, Dynamic**) without noticing any difference—the values still change independently of the governor, even with "Static".

I suspect Dynamic Voltage and Frequency Scaling (DVFS) might be the issue:

```bash
adb shell "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/18500000.mali/dvfs"
adb shell "cat /sys/devices/platform/18500000.mali/dvfs_max_lock"
adb shell "cat /sys/devices/platform/18500000.mali/dvfs_min_lock"
```

However, disabling DVFS doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Has anyone successfully locked the GPU frequency on a Samsung Galaxy S10 or a similar device with a Mali GPU for performance testing? Any insights or references to documentation on managing GPU governors and DVFS on such devices would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the DVSF configuration is provided by the Silicon Provider.